# Trigger iPhone/iPads default photo share screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, share

In iPad/iPhone we have option to click on a pic and choose share button below that brings up the default sharing view. As shown in picture below. Pic 1 is the pic to share and clicking on share button brings up a screen shown in Pic 2
[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

I need to perform same in my app. Is it possible to trigger this default share option? Is there any class for this?

Comment: Read `UIActivityViewController` documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from iOS 6, you can use `UIActivityViewController` to call out the share option box:

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

where `objectsToShare` is a `NSArray` of `UIImage` in your case.

You can even remove some share options with:

```
controller.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
```

before presenting the view controller to the user.

Also, you can modify the sharing content by implementing `UIActivityItemSource` protocol.

---

Update: iOS 7 added AirDrop sharing option

Comment: Is there a separate class for AirDrop? Also is it possible to add a bluetooth share in the UIActivityViewController?

Comment: If BlueTooth is turned ON, there will be AirDrop option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the sharing of text, image ,URl sp on